# Kurzweil Mark 110 digital piano has stuck key

Tags: digital-piano

I have a Kurzweil Mark 110 Digital Piano, that I purchase used.  It is in very good condition, but just recently the B key above middle C will not press down.  It is stuck in the up position.  The adjacent white and black keys are fine.  So questions are:

1. Is there a quick fix for this without having to take apart piano?

   2. I can't find the service manual for the piano (I have the owners manual but it does not describe repairs, other than 'call your local service technician').  I'm fairly handy but it is not obvious how to access the keys on the piano.  It appears that the keys are attached at a point that is under the midi controls and I would have to remove the midi controls somehow.   Can anyone provide guidance?

Thank you

Comment: Dead mouse under the key :-( (Or cookie crumbs, for the squeamish)

Answer (score 1):

If you dare attempting to do this kind of repair work by yourself, my first suggestion would be to take a lot of photos of how things are assembled at every step, so that when you have to put it back together you will know exactly how to do it. Take a photo of every screw before you remove it, every connector before you unplug it, everything.

Having said that, if you're very careful and methodical, you should be able to take off the cover and see whether it's something that you can fix by yourself (e.g. a loose broken piece of plastic having gotten stuck under the key) or something that requires major repairs or spare parts that you don't have). But at least be sure not to make it worse than it is...